# Comic about Mayas and/or Aztecs invading Europe instead of the other way round

Tags: identification-request, comics

I am looking for a alternative-history comic that I saw a few years ago
in which one or more Mesoamerican peoples (the Mayas or the Aztecs or even an alliance of Mesoamerican peoples)
invade Europe, probably during the late Middle Ages.

People have speculated about how that would have turned out if such a thing had happened.
See for example the Quora questions
[What if the Aztecs invaded Europe in the 14th century?](https://www.quora.com/What-if-the-Aztecs-invaded-Europe-in-the-14th-century?share=1)
and
[How would the world have looked in 2013 if the Aztecs, Incas, or Mayans had invented sea-faring and navigation before the Europeans, "discovered" Europe first, and proceeded to colonize them?](https://www.quora.com/How-would-the-world-have-looked-in-2013-if-the-Aztecs-Incas-or-Mayans-had-invented-sea-faring-and-navigation-before-the-Europeans-discovered-Europe-first-and-proceeded-to-colonize-them?share=1)
Some people seem to assume that the Mesoamerican invasion would have failed because the invaders lacked armour and horses,
or because they would have been decimated by a number of European diseases against which they had no immunity.

Apparently, there is also a
[Crusader Kings II game](https://crusaderkings-two.fandom.com/wiki/Aztecs)
based on the premise that the Aztecs set out to conquer the known world.

However, what I am looking for is not a game, a novel or a non-fiction book
but a comic based on this type of premise.
I browsed this comic in a shop that sold comics both in Dutch and in French,
so the comic may have been in either language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Luxley* (2005) by Valérie Mangin and Francisco Ruizgé?

Translated from [Bédéthèque](https://www.bedetheque.com/BD-Luxley-Tome-1-Le-mauvais-oeil-47259.html), adapted from DeepL's translation:

> 1191; the Third Crusade. France and England await the return of their kings, Philip Augustus and Richard the Lionheart, who have gone to fight Saladin. Nothing seems to threaten the Christian West. And yet.. **the unimaginable happens: a huge army of Mayans, Aztecs, and other warriors undertakes a bloody invasion of unarmed Christendom. The New World has dared to invade the Old...**
>
> Eight years have passed. The so-called Atlanteans dominate Europe. All cannot be lost. Robin of Luxley, known as Robin Hood, is convinced of that. Alas, on a secret mission of rebellion, he is captured by the Atlantean governor of France...
>
> What will become of the freedom of the last rebels, the survival of the young King of France and the fate of all Europe?

---

Found with the Google query `bande dessinée aztèques envahissent europe` (`comics aztecs invade europe`).

Comment: That's exactly the one I was looking for. There is also a description in Dutch on [Stripweb.be](https://www.stripweb.be/S-stripverhaal-het-boze-oog-bestellen-8178.asp).